# HTML/CSS: Display image in semicircle in top of modal box

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a requirement of displaying the image/icon on top of the modal box in a semicircle. Though I have achieved it with the help of below code, but the only issue is whenever my form in the modal box goes for a validation check, displaying any error, my semicircle doesn't get adjusted accordingly, rather it stays at its position. Here, I have attached the screen shot of what exactly I am looking for and HTML/css code I have used to display the semicircle with image/icon at the top.[image: Expected Design] [image: Design distortion on validation message]

```css
.modal {
  font-family: Avenir-Medium;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  display: block;
  /*Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
  -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
  /* Fade in the background */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2.0s;
  /* Fade in the background */
  ;
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  width: 92%;
  left: 14px;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  border-radius: 16px 16px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  top: auto;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  line-height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e9ea;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
}

.modal-wrapper::after {
  background: url("../../../../images/mobile/img-payment_38.png") no-repeat 22px 10px;
  background-size: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  content: '';
  width: 78px;
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 78px 78px 0 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #e7e9ea;
  border-top: 1px solid #e7e9ea;
  border-right: 1px solid #e7e9ea;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
  bottom: 300px;
}

.close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: top;
  top: 4px;
  left: 320px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}

.container-div-creditCard {
  margin: 12px 20px 0px 20px;
}

.container-div-creditCard>img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 154px;
  right: 30px;
}

.credit-card-modal-label {
  font-family: AvenirHeavy;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #1d3444;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 200;
  height: 24px;
  margin-left: 31px;
}

.input-modal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
}

.input-spacing {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.credit-input-modal {
  border: solid 1px #e7e9ea;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Avenir-Book;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #8589a1;
  line-height: initial;
  padding: 13px 42px 12px 15px;
}

.credit-expiry-input-modal {
  padding: 13px 27px 12px 10px;
  border: solid 1px #e7e9ea;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Avenir-Book;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #8589a1;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: initial;
  width: 65%;
  height: 44px;
}

.credit-cvc-input-modal {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 17px 5px 12px 10px;
  border: solid 1px #e7e9ea;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Avenir-Book;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #8589a1;
  line-height: initial;
  height: 44px;
}

.cvvDisc {
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
}

.credit-submit-button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 13px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border: solid 1px #e7e9ea;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #e32490, #ed1a3d);
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: Avenir-Book;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: initial;
}

.errorMsg {
  font-family: Avenir-Book;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #ED1A3D;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="modalCCDetails" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content modal-wrapper">
    <div class="container-div-creditCard">
      <label class="credit-card-modal-label">ENTER YOUR CREDIT CARD DETAILS</label>
      <input name="cc_name" class="input-modal credit-input-modal" type="text" placeholder="Name printed on Credit Card" onChange={this.handleUserInput} />
      <span class="errorMsg"></span>
      <input name="cc_number" class="input-modal credit-input-modal input-spacing" type="tel" maxLength="16" onKeyPress={(e)=> this.handleCCOnKeyPress(e)} placeholder="16 digit credit card number" />
      <span class="errorMsg"></span>
      <input name="cc_expDate" class="credit-expiry-input-modal" type="text" placeholder="Expiry MM-YYYY" />
      <div class="device-divider" />
      <input name="cc_cvc" class="credit-cvc-input-modal cvvDisc" type="tel" placeholder="CVC" maxLength="3" />
      <span class="errorMsg"></span>
    </div>
    <button class="credit-submit-button">Submit Payment</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** This is a mobile view screenshot

Comment: We can't help without proper code. Please share more code and url, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: @jaydeeppatel Thats the code I am using in my react application , I provided the HTML removing the react code from it, currently there is no URL where this code is deployed hence can't provide that

Comment: Have you tried adding `top: 0px;` to .modal-wrapper:after?

Comment: @ashu add top attribute in .modal-wrapper::after { top: -15px; } u will see the image move up

Comment: @HuyNguyen that worked.... I used `top:-44px;` and removed `bottom:300px;`, please add your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adjust your css code into something like this:

```
.modal-wrapper::after {
  background: url("../../../../images/mobile/img-payment_38.png") no-repeat 22px 10px;
  background-size: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  content: '';
  width: 78px;
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 78px 78px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid  #e7e9ea;
  border-bottom: 3px`enter code here` solid white;
  top: -48px;
}
```

Just remove the bottom: 300px; and replace with top: -48px; or any value that you want.

Comment: Using a percentage in absolute positioning is not the best idea when it comes to responsive web design. It will cause the element to get further and further away from where its meant to be when the screensize becomes bigger.

Answer (score 1):

please add `top:-15px;` and removed `bottom:300px;` in class `.modal-wrapper::after { top: -15px; }`, u will see the image move up